# How to set silent alarm on htc one X

Tags: htc-one-x, alarm

In the alarm settings, there is no "silent" ringtone. I only want the phone to vibrate in the morning.

Any hints?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have Clock app available in your Android Jelly Bean, Open it and set alarm with silent ringtone and you chek the box to vibrate.

In Jelly Bean 4.2.1 the silent ringtone is there. If you don't have, install ES file explorer, record some silent ringtone and set it with ES explorer.

Comment: I can not find the silent ringtone, modified the question accordingly.

Comment: I have edited my answer above.